# Php combine Multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have array as follows

```
array (A => 1)
array (A => 1, B=>2)
array (A => 1, B=>2, C=>3)
array (A => 1, D=>4)
array (A => 1, E=>5)
array (A => 1, F=>6)
array (A => 1, F=>6, G=>8)
array (A => 1, F=>6, H=>9)
array (X => 11)
array (X => 11, Y=22)
array (X => 11, Z=33)
```

I need to form array as follows

```
array(A=>array(B=>2, C=>3, D=>4, E=>5, F=>array(G=>8,H=>9))
  X=>array(Y=>22, Z=>33)
```

Comment: What is the rule behind this?

Comment: are you looking for some function that do what you are looking?

Comment: Yes. I am looking for function.

Comment: your array dont seems correct ,if not explain a bit how array being generated

Comment: See 3rd line array (A => 1, B=>2, C=>3) is duplicated in first 2 line so it should be in new array

Comment: There are a lot of syntax errors in that.  It really makes it hard to tell what you're trying to do:   array (X => 11, Y=22), array (X => 11, Z=33) are missing operators.  The result array is not valid and therefore it's unclear what is supposed to be nested where.

Comment: Below array is also unique
array (A => 1, D=>4) 
array (A => 1, E=>5) 

Array array (A => 1, F=>6) is duplicated in array (A => 1, F=>6, G=>8) so we just use array (A => 1, F=>6, G=>8) and array (A => 1, F=>6, H=>9)

array (X => 11)  is duplicated in array (X => 11, Y=22) so we just use array  (X => 11, Y=22) and (X => 11, Z=33)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you’re looking for:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    $ref = &$result;
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if (!isset($ref[$key])) {
            $ref[$key] = $val;
        } elseif (!is_array($ref[$key])) {
            $ref[$key] = array();
        }
        $ref = &$ref[$key];
    }
}
```

Here the keys are interpreted as path segments to walk the array using a reference. If there is no value yet, the value is stored; if there already is a value, it is replaced by an array.

But this is generating a little different result:

```
array (
  'A' => 
  array (
    'B' => 
    array (
      'C' => 3,
    ),
    'D' => 4,
    'E' => 5,
    'F' => 
    array (
      'G' => 8,
      'H' => 9,
    ),
  ),
  'X' => 
  array (
    'Y' => 22,
    'Z' => 33,
  ),
)
```

Comment: @JapanPro: Where is it in the expected result in the question?

Comment: Gumbo, it should work for multidimentional array. And multidimentional array could be upto 10

Comment: @user459588: What multidimensional array? Can you give an example of such an array?

Comment: array(A=>array(B=>2, C=>3, D=>4, E=>5, F=>array(G=>8,H=>9)) 
  X=>array(Y=>22, Z=>33)

Comment: See array element F=>array(G=>8, H=>9, k=array(P=>121, Q=>444, R=>array(J=99, L=101))

Comment: @user459588: That’s what you’re wrote in the question. How does my proposal does not fit this result (apart from that *B* is also an array containing *C*)?

Comment: @user459588: Please be more specific. Give examples for input and expected output.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811232/php-multidimentional-array