# Php Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have below multidimensional array

```
$testarray=Array
(
    1 => Array
        (
            0 => 'A',
            1 => 'B'
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            0 => 'A',
            1 => 'C'
        ),

    3 => Array
        (
            0 => 'A',
            1 => 'C',
            2 => 'D'
        ),

    4 => Array
        (
            0 => 'A',
            1 => 'C',
            2 => 'E'
        ),
   5 => Array
        (
            0 => 'X',
            1 => 'Y'
        ),

    6 => Array
        (
            0 => 'X',
            1 => 'Y',
            2 => 'Z'
        ),

    7 => Array
        (
            0 => 'X',
            1 => 'Y',
            2 => 'ZZ'
        ),

    8 => Array
        (
            0 => 'P',
            1 => 'Q'
        ),

    9 => Array
        (
            0 => 'P',
            1 => 'Q',
            2 => 'R'
        ),

    10 => Array
        (
            0 => 'P',
            1 => 'Q',
            2 => 'R',
            3 => 'S'
        )
);
```

I need to generate below array using `$testarray` (aultidimentional array):

```
array(A=array(B, C=array(D,E)), 
 X=array(Y=>array(Z,ZZ)), 
 P=array(Q=>array(R=>array(S))
```

Comment: Please tell about the purpose of doing such an illogical part. I can't conclude what is the main reason of doing such.

Comment: you should rephrase your question to better explain tha logic behind the transformation you need to perform

Comment: Actually i stored category and subcategories depth in following format against each record.
A|B (1st array)
A|C
A|C|D
A|C|E
X|Y
X|Y|Z
X|Y|ZZ
P|Q
P|Q|R
P|Q|R|S (10 array)

After exploding each array using | delimiter, i got $testarray. And i need to store output array in json format for further processing

Comment: How is this different from your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804876?

Comment: No difference but it gives me below errors
Notice: Array to string conversion in ... for line $ref[$key] = array(); 
Fatal error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets nor overloaded objects in ...for line  $ref = &$ref[$key];

Comment: @Rahul: The input in both cases is different: Here the keys (A, B, C, etc.) are the values of the array and in the other question they are the keys of the array. That means you need to change what part of the array is used as key. In this case change `foreach ($array as $key => $val)` to `foreach ($array as $key)` and `$ref[$key] = $val;` to `$ref[$key] = null;`.

Comment: Now error for $ref = &$ref[$key]; because $ref[$key]=null. Many thanks for helping

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets nor overloaded objects in....

Answer (score 0):

At least in the version of PHP I use you can do something like

```
$testArray = Array(
    1 => Array(
        'A'=> Array(
              //Value of A here
         )
         'B' => Array(
              //Value of B here
          )
  );
```

To access them you can write

```
$testArray[1]['A'];
```

If you can change the value of $testArray this should help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Any refinements (and explanations) would be appreciated.

```
foreach( $testarray as $values ) {
    $depth = count($values);
    $ref =& $array;

    for( $i=0; $i<$depth; $i++ ) {
        if( $i == $depth-1 ) {
            $ref[] = $values[$i];
        }
        else {
            if( !is_array( $ref ) || !array_key_exists( $values[$i], $ref ) ) {
                $ref[$values[$i]] = array();
            }
            if( ( $key = array_search( $values[$i], $ref ) ) !== FALSE ) {
                unset( $ref[$key] );
            }
            $ref =& $ref[$values[$i]];
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 array
  'A' => 
    array
      0 => string 'B' (length=1)
      'C' => 
        array
          0 => string 'D' (length=1)
          1 => string 'E' (length=1)
  'X' => 
    array
      'Y' => 
        array
          0 => string 'Z' (length=1)
          1 => string 'ZZ' (length=2)
  'P' => 
    array
      'Q' => 
        array
          'R' => 
            array
              0 => string 'S' (length=1)
```